# Passing string(a paragraph) using command line argument to powershell script in php

Tags: php, powershell, command-line-arguments

I'm executing `Shell_Exec()` using php in the following way:

```
$com='C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -InputFormat none -command ".\"'.$pshell_path.'"" "'.$name.'" "'.$pbody.'" < NUL';
$Result = Shell_Exec ($com);
```

where `$pshell_path` is path to powershell script, `$name` contains names and `$pbody` is declared as follows:

```
$pbody = "Ignore this mail. This is a test mail. Multiline text mail. Hello world"
```

which is some paragraph of text. When I execute `Shell_Exec()` $pbody variable will have only first word **Ignore** and not the whole paragraph. How to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$pbody = "Ignore this mail. This is a test mail. Multiline text mail. Hello world";

$pshell_path = '/root';
$name = 'Username';
  
$com="C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -InputFormat none -command .\\$pshell_path $name '$pbody' < NUL";

echo 'My Command line is: '. $com;

$result = Shell_Exec ($com);

?>
```

Comment: In this case, it prints correctly in php before executing the command and when I check from powershell, nothing is getting passed in command line @Mariano

Comment: in your $pshell_path you are calling another powershell script?

Comment: Yes. That is the only powershell script

Comment: Did you try to copy the command line printed after 'My Command line is:' and paste and run it?

Comment: No. I need to execute in php.

Comment: this for sure, but I need to understand if the command printed, are working or not

Comment: How will i do that?

Comment: copy the command line printed from php, and try to run it into the terminal/cmd

Comment: I tried. It is showing only Ignore there also